# Zend Form changing element type in controller

Tags: zend-framework, hidden

I have my Zend_Form, and sometimes, one of the fields should be hidden, and not seen by the user. Is there a way when I call the form in my controller, I could change one of the fields to be hidden?

Thanks
Kousha

Answer (score 3):

You can *remove* the element using:

```
$form->removeElement('my-element-name');
```

in the controller.

You could also create two forms, one overriding the other, in which the child calls `$this->remove('my-element-name')`.

Or, you could make the form constructor accept a boolean `$flag` that determines whether to add the field to the form.

So, as you can see, lots of different ways to structure it.

To change that field to one of type "hidden" (i.e. `<input type="hidden">`) is a different thing, but I'm not sure that's what you mean/need/want.

Comment: another way is to extend the form class and eliminate the undesired elements.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I have for this is to add a specific class to the element when it needs to be hidden.  It may not be the perfect solution, but let me explain.

First, its very difficult to switch from one element type to another in Zend Form.  Your elements are actually classes.  So the text is Zend_Form_Element_Text - so its not just as easy as changing the 'type' attribute.

If the element must remain on the form (so, not removing it like the answer above suggests), your only other option would be hiding it with CSS.

Try the following code when it needs to be hidden:

```
$element = $form->getElement('MyElement');
$newClass = trim($element->getAttrib('class') . ' hidden');
$element->setAttrib('class', $newClass);
```

Then, of course, create CSS for the .hidden class.

Hope this helps!